# Loading info based on data hardcoded into an image

Tags: android, xml, dictionary, metadata, hardcoded

I'm using some map based images in an Android app, and each map includes numbered waypoints and highlit paths between each waypoint. This map data has all been hard-coded into the map image.

My client would like to be able to click on each waypoint and display some associated info in a popup. So would anyone be able to suggest what might be the easiest way to attach the popup data to the image based waypoint location?

I thought perhaps using an image recognition algorithm to scan for each way point position, but that probably wouldn't be completely accurate and also resource intensive.

Is my only feasible option to ask the client to supply something like associated xml metadata for each waypoint location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely go the route of additional data. It would be way too expensive to extract the points on the go.

Although you'll have some fun translating the points on the map to points on the screen.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. When you say 'some fun', does that mean t would also be quite difficult? I haven't done any map work before so I'm only guessing, and I figured associated map metadata is how most mapping applications work.

Comment: You'll just need a way to translate a point on the 2d map tile to a relative position on screen (which will have to account for zooming, panning, rotation etc). It's not exactly hard but it's non trivial.

Comment: Cool thanks, much appreciated! I'll have a look at some existing open source mapping apps to get some ideas. Don't suppose anyone might have suggestion which app to look at? ;-)

Comment: Nah sorry, could it be worth just using Google Maps?

Comment: Could be, I've not used it in an android app but it's as good a starting point as any. thanks ;-)